# Time returned by timeval structure is wrong in Ubuntu

Tags: c, select, timeval

I am trying to see the time taken by select function to moniter files, but when I try to print it, I get a very long number.Here is the code:

```
struct timeval to;
to.tv_usec=25;
nfds=select(maxfds+1,&readset,NULL,NULL,&to);
printf("Time left for monitering the file descriptors %d\n",to);
```

What is the reason for this weird behavior? This is code works fine with `to.tv_sec`.

[image]

Regards

Comment: Can you show an example output?

Comment: Please note that changing the value of tv by select() is a Linuxism. Also: you could printf *both* members of to : ` " ... ors {%d,%d}\n", (int) to.tv_sec, (int) to.tv_usec);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a struct to printf() that way.  Pass one of its members or a value created from them.

If you trace the definition of a timeval struct down to implementation-specific detail, you will likely find something like this:

```
struct timeval
  {
    __time_t tv_sec;    /* Seconds.  */
    __suseconds_t tv_usec;  /* Microseconds.  */
  };
```

What this says is that there is a construct in memory which (at least on this particular platform) consists of a value in seconds followed in memory by a value of microseconds.  These two values constitute the members of the struct.

A function such as select() needs to be given a pointer to the struct itself.  A pointer to the first member might often have the same raw memory address as its value, but is not formally or portably interchangeable and should result in warnings if misused as a struct pointer.

A generic plain-value function like printf() has no knowledge of timeval structs, and so must be given either struct members which can be interpreted as numeric types which it does understand, or values created by combining struct members.  For example, it's quite common to use both fields to calculate a 64-bit time in milliseconds and display that with 64-bit printf format specifier.

Comment: Ok even when I pass only a member of the timeval structure in select function for example to.tv_sec, select uses both tv_sec and tv_usec. Why is that

Comment: Pass a pointer to a timeval structure to select() as that is what it requires, but pass either member variables or something calculated from them to printf() as it does not understand timeval structs.  On a platform where tv_sec is the first member of a timeval struct, a pointer to that member would likely have the same raw value (memory address) as a pointer to the struct itself so would be interpreted as such if you manage to ignore the improper cast.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your other problem is that you didn't initialize the value of the struct. You declare it, which creates it on the stack with whatever garbage data was left there. Then you set only the tv_usec member.

It would be better to declare and initialize it like this: `struct timeval to = {0, 25};` That would guarantee that all of the struct fields are set.